# http GET requests getting Timed Out on Heroku App (PERN stack) | Error Code: H12

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, heroku-postgres

http GET requests getting Timed Out on my Heroku Deployed App, while it works perfectly fine on my local machine.

I am fetching data from simple queries on a PostgreSQL database.

Here's the Heroku App -->
https://fyle-fullstack-app.herokuapp.com/ and API's --> https://fyle-fullstack-app.herokuapp.com/api/branches?q=bangalore&limit=100 and postgres dump--> https://github.com/snarayanank2/indian_banks

The fact is 2-3 requests with same queries are working, but others are not. (I guess those were cached before commit).

Here's the Heroku's Error Logs -->

```
2021-01-10T09:38:39.959014+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12
desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/branches?q=Kolkata" host=fyle-
fullstack-app.herokuapp.com request_id=3e184180-6b37-4846-930b-ddf6ace39f1d
fwd="157.45.169.72" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
protocol=https
```

Console Logs :

```
GEThttps://fyle-fullstack-app.herokuapp.com/api/branches?q=Ahmedabad

[HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable 30565ms]

XHRGEThttps://fyle-fullstack-app.herokuapp.com/api/branches?q=Kolkata
[HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable 31892ms]

JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data backend.js:6:2315
```

Comment: are you using any other addons except PostgreSQL?

Comment: @SLDem No, just the hobby-dev plan for postgres.

Comment: can you add the complete heroku log?